# Restriction map to a non-reduced divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface over $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose $C$ is a smooth divisor (can assume irreducible curve) on $X$. For $1\leq m<N$ be integers. Let $NC$ and $mC$  be non-reduced divisors. Let $i:mC\hookrightarrow X$ denote the inclusion. My question is the following : can we have a surjective restriction morphism :

$$O_X(mC)\rightarrow i_* O_X(NC)|_{mC}\,?$$

The context is as follows, I saw a paper where it seems to say the following. Suppose $E$ is a vector bundle of rank two on $X$. If $A$ is a line bundle on $mC$ which is a quotient of $E|_{mC}$. Then there is a surjective restriction map from $E\otimes O_X(mC)\rightarrow i_*(A\otimes O_X(NC)|_{mC})$.

If my claim is correct then I will be able to prove the above statement from the paper.

Thanks!

Comment: Everything is OK when $N = m$. The case $N > m$ looks strange.

Comment: @Sasha, exactly. But $\frac{m}{N}<1$ in the paper. I don't know what the morphism is even.

Comment: Hard to say without other details.

Comment: @Sasha, as far I can see, this is supposed to work in general. Would you like to see the reference?

Comment: I can try to look.

Comment: @Sasha, thanks! This is from the paper 'Parabolic bundles as Orbifold bundles' by Indranil Biswas in Duke Mathematical journal in 1997. This is in Page 313, equation (3.4). I am taking the simpler case of a rank two vector bundle.

Comment: I strongly suspect that $m_l = N$ and so the twist is the same, Biswas could easily make some confusing misprint in indices.

Comment: @Sasha, ah the standing assumption is that the weights $\frac{m_i}{N}$ are all strictly $<1$. I am just wondering if there is a misprint elsewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57756/discussion-between-sasha-and-user349424).